# Saving a custom class in an array to be saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm creating an app that will create a form which a user will then fill out and save for later use.

```
@interface DataModel : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *whiskeyName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *whiskeyRating;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *whiskeyColor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *whiskeyNose;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *whiskeyFlavors;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *whiskeyFinish;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *whiskeyNotes;
```

The app will store multiple copies of these forms (think of Apple's Notes app). I've created a class composed of `NSStrings` and `NSNumbers` but I'm having a difficult time figuring out a way save them to an `NSArray` to access later. I've just started fooling around with Core Data but everything I've found will only save a single form. How can I save multiple versions of a class in an array to be opened and edited for later use? Sorry if the question is vague, but I've been hitting my head on a wall and am having a hard time finding a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have sub-classed NSObject and want to save multiple instances of this class into an array? If that is the case, then a MutableArray should be able to hold any object:

```
// .m file
#import "DataModel.h"

@interface YourViewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end

@implementation YourViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfObjectsToStore];

    DataModel *myClassInstance1 = [[DataModel alloc] init];
    myClassInstance1.whiskeyName= @"somevalue";
    myClassInstance1.whiskeyRating= 5;

    DataModel *myClassInstance2 = [[DataModel alloc] init];
    myClassInstance2.whiskeyName= @"someothervalue";
    myClassInstance2.whiskeyRating= 2;

    [myArray addObject:myClassInstance1];
    [myArray addObject:myClassInstance2];

}
```